# Using a client-side only, readable store `set`, to refresh API access token

Tags: sveltekit, svelte-3, svelte-store

I am experimenting with using a readable store as the auth token for a web app.

The `set` function would fetch an authentication token from an API, and then set a timeout for X seconds to refresh the token before it expires. This would then continuously run every X seconds to set the token.

*// auth.ts*

```js
export const ssr = false;

type LoginResponse = {
  access_token: string;
  expires: string;
}

export const authToken: Readable<string> = readable("", (set) => {

  const setAuth = async () => {
    const auth: LoginResponse = await authenticate();
    set(auth.access_token);
    authTimer(auth);
  };

  const authTimer = async (auth: LoginResponse) => {
    const timeRemaining = Math.round(((new Date(auth.expires).getTime() - Date.now())) * 0.9);
    setTimeout(async () => {
      if (auth.access_token === authToken) {
         console.log("refreshing auth token");
         setAuth();
      }
    }, timeRemaining);
  }

  setTimeout(setAuth, 0)
});
```

- The main issue I'm having is that this `set` function is called from the backend, causing an exception to raise when the `authenticate()` call fails. It should only be called once the front-end is loaded, as there needs to be client side headers set for the request to succeed.

Is this a generally good approach or is this not what set is intended for?

- Also I seem to be unable to make value comparisons with the value of the readable (e.g. `auth.access_token === authToken` will always return false).
- Finally, how can I queue API calls to only execute when the `authToken` is not an empty string?